# Which Versions of "Android Development Tools" are most Promising/Compatible with Gingerbread & In which order, they should be installed?

Tags: android

Please tell that which Versions of (Android Development Tools i.e. Java JDK, Android SDK, Eclipse & ADT Plugin) are MOST Compatible/Promising with 2.3 Gingerbread & in which Order I should Install them. please mention, if some tool is omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The latest ones all work fine.

Install order should be:

1. JDK
2. Eclipse (Helios).
3. Android SDK
4. Eclipse ADT

Comment: Yes they will.  Under Windows, I tend to install development tools/SDKs under C:\Develop.